# ¿Como pasar a un servlet varios parámetros (algunos con comas) a través de la URL?

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

Tengo que recibir en el servlet (java) unos parámetros desde un jsp, los cuales se pasan por la URL. Estos dos parámetros están concatenados con el símbolo "_" en el parámetro myid que es el que tengo que pasar. Os pongo un ejemplo:

```
id = '1';
codigo = 'A,B,C';
myid=1_A,B,C
"url?myid=1_A,B,C"
```

Cuando intento pasar el myid que os he puesto, solo estoy recibiendo el primer parámetro, es decir el 1. Parece ser que no le gustan las comas
Alguien sabe como puedo pasarle esto al servlet sabiendo que puede haber comas en este segundo parametro

Comment: Tendrás que codificar los parámetros. Por ejemplo: `url?myid=1_A%2CB%2CC`. Luego al recibirlo debes decodificarlo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Debes de usar el método de codificación de URL, por lo general se usa ASCII Hex.

Puedes ver el sitio  [http://www.asciitable.com/](https://www.asciitable.com/)  para determinar tu cadena.
Prueba con "1_A%2CB%2CC"

Saludos.